# Getting infinite recursion with ObjectMapper even though entities' fields are annotated with @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, infinite-recursion

Got two entities:

```
class Entity1{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "entity1Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer entity1Id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity1", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
Set<Entity2> entity2set = new Hashset<>(); 

}

class Entity2 {
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "entity1Id")
private Entity1 entity1;
}
```

No matter how I annotate those fields with @JsonIgnore or @JsonIgnoreProperties, I still get infinite recursion when I try to:

```
Entity1 entity1 = dao.saveEntity1(fields...);
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(entity1);

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.hibernate.Entity1["entity2set"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->gis.hibernate.Entity2["entity1"]->gis.hibernate.Entity1["entity2set"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]-> ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Here are the attempts that I tried:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("entity1")
private Set<Entity2> entity2set = new HashSet<>();
together with
@JsonIgnoreProperties("entity2set")
private Entity1 entity1;

@JsonIgnore
private Entity1 entity1; (inside Entity2)

@JsonIgnore
private Set<Entity2> entity2set = new HashSet<>();  (inside Entity1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: @SternK actually no, I also tried JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference. Object Mapper still getting infinite recursion. I don't understand..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` incorrectly. It is supposed to be on the class level.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with JsonView and with

```
String json = new ObjectMapper().writerWithView(MyView.class).writeValueAsString(entity);
```

This was the only thing that worked for me